# Python3, best alternatives to eval()? (input as an expression)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.

How can I input an expression without using `eval(input("Input: "))`?

I needed eval for an algebra calculator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on how complicated your expressions are, `ast.literal_eval` may be a safer alternative.

Comment: `literal_eval()` would only evaluate literals, not algebraic expressions.

Answer (score 7):

If you're the only person using that app and thus don't need to be worried about security issues, just keep using `eval()` or `exec()`.

Otherwise, just use a safe library for the specific task you need. E.g. [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) I guess for a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

The asteval module was explicitly created for the OP's use case; a safer eval.

See https://newville.github.io/asteval/motivation.html

Answer (score -5):

> how can I input an expression without using eval(input("Input: "))

Simply don’t use `eval`. In Python 3.x, `input` is the replacement for `raw_input`, so you don't need `eval`. You can simply write your statement as `input("Input: ")`.

Moreover, in Python 2.X, you should have used `raw_input("Input: ")` instead of `eval(input("Input: "))`.

Comment: But that won't address the OP's use case, which is "an algebra calculator".

Comment: You don't seem to understand, input() is only for strings, or I could add int() or float(), but I need to input expressions like (3 * x - 3), which seem to work only with eval.