# Accept a user input in string (a numerical expression) and evaluate its value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string and I need to evaluate its numerical value, e.g. `a='5.1+2.3-1.9'`

I tried using type conversion but it's not working. Error "Could not convert string to float".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`, but this means that it will evaluate everything what you put in there, even: `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /a-path-you-really-care-about')` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197726/10961342)).

A better solution was provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21661162/10961342) stackoverflow (SO) post and advises you to use something like [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr), which are a lot safer.

Comment: eval returns int value..expected output is float.

Comment: @Sreyans `eval('5.1+2.3-1.9')` returns 5.5 for me. What version of Python are you using, and what are you running exactly?

Comment: @Sreyans I get the same results as @wjandrea, which is `5.5` for the example that you posted.