# Take List of Lists as Input and Output The Individual List inside the List of Lists

Tags: python

I am trying to take a 2D list and print out the individuals list inside.

Something like:
If the user enters the 2D list: `"[[a,b],[c,d],[e],[f,g]]"`

Required output should be:

```
[a,b]
[c,d]
[e]
[f,g]
```

###### The following is the current code I have but it does not work as intended:

```py
alist = []
UserInput = input("Enter 2D list = ")
alist.append(UserInput)
        
for row in alist:
    print(row)
```

Comment: `input` returns a *string*. The following string: `"[[a,b],[c,d],[e],[f,g]]"` would represent a valid list literal (which is *source code*, i.e. text), but if you evaluated that text as source code it would raise a `NameError`, because non of the variables you referenced are defined

Answer (score 0):

(I'm new on stack overflow so I don't know if I'm answering correctly). You have to replace just 3 line of your code:

```
list = list(eval(input(" Enter 2D list = "))
for row in list: 
    print(row)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Some python tips: 1) ast.literal_eval() is generally preferable to eval(). If you're working with untrusted input, then you should use ast.literal_eval(), because it won't evaluate arbitrary code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661090/python3-best-alternatives-to-eval-input-as-an-expression 2) You should avoid using variables named "list", because they will shadow the built-in function list.

Answer (score 0):

#### There is a key difference between these two strings:

```py
str1 = "[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e'],['f','g']]"

str2 = "[[a,b],[c,d],[e],[f,g]]"
```

The first string `(str1)` is a pure representation of string list of lists which have strings inside lists. But in the second string `(str2)`, the list of lists is made up of variables like `a, b, c`. These are not strings and will cause error if you try to print the lists of it. Check this:

```py
print([[a,b],[c,d],[e],[f,g]])  # will throw error as undefined variables
```

The first string `(str1)` can be easily convert to list of lists using **[ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)**

Check this:

```py
import ast
str1 = "[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e'],['f','g']]"

str_lists = ast.literal_eval(str1)

for lst in str_lists :
    print(lst)

#Output
>>> ['a', 'b']
    ['c', 'd']
    ['e']
    ['f', 'g']
```

> ## In your case

Your case is likely to be the case of second string `(str2)` since it will assume the list as a whole string itself.

```
str2 = "[[a,b],[c,d],[e],[f,g]]"
```

If you try to use **ast** in this case, it will throw error as it contains variables inside list instead of strings.

```py
str2 = "[[a,b],[c,d],[e],[f,g]]"

str_lists = ast.literal_eval(str2)

# it throws error
for lst in str_lists:
    print(lst)
```

So, in order to solve this, you need to use the concept of stack for balanced parentheses. Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-python/)

##### Solution:

```py
def convert_to_list(myStr):
    open_list = ["[","{","("]
    close_list = ["]","}",")"]
    
    myStr = myStr.replace(',',' ')
    stack = []
    stack_ind = []
    new_list = []
    for innd, i in enumerate(myStr):
        if i in open_list:
            stack.append(i)
            stack_ind.append(innd)
        elif i in close_list:
            pos = close_list.index(i)
            
            if ((len(stack) > 0) and
                (open_list[pos] == stack[len(stack)-1])):
                nstr = myStr[stack_ind[-1]+1:innd]
                new_list.append(nstr.split())
                stack.pop()
    new_list.remove(new_list[-1])
    return new_list

UserInput = input("Enter 2D list = ")
input_list = convert_to_list(UserInput)
for lst in input_list:
    print(lst)

#Output
>>>  ['a', 'b']
     ['c', 'd']
     ['e']
     ['f', 'g']
```