# Segmentation Fault while using Python lib in C with Python.h

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, python-embedding

This is my first time asking a question on stack overflow so please bear with me
I am trying to create a calculator in c as a project but I am getting a segmentation fault when evaluating a algebraic expression for second time using a python lib inside c using Python.h 
At first I was using the [eval function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eval-in-python/) directly provided by the python interpreter but after reading about [why eval can be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/) I used a python lib named [NumExpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661090/) but when I use that python library to evaluate the algebraic expression I get a segmentation fault on entering the expression second time (it works for the first time)
Here is the example code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python.h>

void my_pause()
{
    int c;
    printf("\n  Press the enter key to continue...");
    fflush(stdout);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}

void main()
{
    char selec[8], temp;

    while(1)
    {
        main:

        printf("Enter here : ");
        scanf("%s" , selec);
        scanf("%c" , &temp); //this scanf is necessary as it solves the input buffer

        if(strcmp(selec,"math-exp")==0)
        {
            printf("\n\n  Please note the opreators : ");
            printf("\n    for addition '+'");
            printf("\n    for subtraction '-'");
            printf("\n    for multiplication '*'");
            printf("\n    for division '/'");
            printf("\n    for exponential power '**'");
            printf("\n    for percentage '%%'");
            printf("\n    for knowing about various functions that can be used please check documentation");

            //I had to print this using printf and not by python print itself is to solve the EOL error
            printf("\n\n  Enter the mathematical expression : ");
            Py_Initialize();
            PyRun_SimpleString("import numexpr as ne");
            PyRun_SimpleString("math_exp = input()");
            //I had to print this using printf and not by python print itself is to solve the EOL error
            printf("\n  The answer is : ");
            fflush(stdout);
            PyRun_SimpleString("print(math_exp)");
            Py_Finalize();

            my_pause();
            system("clear");
            goto main;
        }
        else if(strcmp(selec,"exit")==0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine for the first time but if you enter 'math-exp' for the second time to enter another expression it will show the segmentation fault. I am using linux mint, gcc 9.4.0, python 3.8. Below is the command I am using to compile the code : 
gcc test.c -o test.bin -I"/usr/include/python3.8" -L"/usr/lib/python3.8" -lpython3.8

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Don't be so tight with the buffer, which is ready to overflow at the first sneeze. `char selec[8]; scanf("%s" , selec);` ==> `char selec[100]; scanf("%99s" , selec);`.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, `char selec[8];` is too small to contain the string `"math-exp"` which requires at least 9 characters (8 for the text + 1 for a null terminator)

Comment: Well thank you for helping me with that but my main problem is still not sloved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Py_Finalize` multiple times creates memory leaks. Just move your `Py_Finalize` line before `exit(0)`
This bug has been opened in 2007, and just closed last month. https://bugs.python.org/issue1635741
Solved in python 3.11.

Comment: Thanks, This work perfectly fine for me but will it cause any other issues?

Comment: Unless you use multiple python threads, I don't think so.

Comment: Ok so then it works for me as I use only a single python thread, thank you so much